# Updating multiple rows in a single transaction in Slick 3.1.x

Tags: scala, slick, slick-3.0

Assume a table `table1` has three columns `col1`, `col2` and `col3`. Also, assume I need to update `col1` based on the value of `col2`. For example, with the following SQL statement

```
update table1 set col1=111 where col2=222
```

Let's also say I have to update 1000 times `table1` and I have the information in the following `Seq`:

```
case class Table1 (col1: Int, col2: Int, col3: Int)
val list = Seq(Table1(111,222,333),Table1(111,333,444), .... )
```

What's the best way to update 1000 rows in Slick 3.1.x? Is it possible to run a batch statement with `foreach`?

```
 val action = table1.foreach(....)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `DBIO.sequence` to build a list of actions to execute, something like this:

```
db.run(DBIO.sequence(list.map(l => ???)))
```

Here is a more complete example:

```
import scala.concurrent.Await
import scala.concurrent.duration.Duration
import slick.driver.H2Driver.api._


object main {

    // The class and corresponding table
    case class Thing (id: String, col1: Int, col2: Int)
    class Things(tag: Tag) extends Table[Thing](tag, "things") {
        def id = column[String]("id", O.PrimaryKey)
        def col1 = column[Int]("col1")
        def col2 = column[Int]("col2")

        def * = (id, col1, col2) <> ((Thing.apply _).tupled, Thing.unapply)
    }

    val things = TableQuery[Things]


    def main(args: Array[String]) {

        val db = Database.forConfig("h2mem1")

        try {

            // Create schema
            Await.result(db.run(things.schema.create), Duration.Inf)

            // Insert some things for testing
            Await.result(db.run(DBIO.seq(
                things += Thing("id4", 111, 111),
                things += Thing("id5", 222, 222),
                things += Thing("id6", 333, 333)
            )), Duration.Inf)

            // List of things to update
            val list = Seq(Thing("id1", 111, 112), Thing("id2", 222, 223), Thing("id3", 333, 334))

            // ----- The part you care about is here -----
            // Create a list of Actions to update
            val actions = DBIO.sequence(list.map(current => {

                // Whatever it is you want to do here
                things.filter(_.col1 === current.col1).update(current)
            }))

            // Run the actions
            Await.result(db.run(actions), Duration.Inf).value

            // Print out the results
            val results = Await.result(db.run(things.result), Duration.Inf)
            println(results)


        } 
        finally db.close
    }
}
```

The output has the updated `col2` values:

```
Vector(Thing(id1,111,112), Thing(id2,222,223), Thing(id3,333,334))
```

Comment: Thanks. Can a `DBIO.sequence` action be part of a transaction (i.e. using `transactionally`) ?

Comment: Yes - it's normal `DBIO`. So you can e.g. do `Await.result(db.run(actions.transactionally), Duration.Inf).value`